# Mockito throws InvalidUseOfMatchersException while mocking a method

Tags: java, mocking, mockito, matcher

I have a test which only contains this line:

```
when(service.getDTO(Matchers.<DatePeriod>any(), anyLong())).thenReturn(getMockedDTO);
```

when I run the test it throws the following error:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Invalid use of argument matchers!
1 matchers expected, 2 recorded.
```

The interface of the method I'm mocking is as follows:

```
DTO getDTO(DatePeriod period, long id);
```

I simply cannot see what I'm doing wrong here.. hopefully someone can guide me in the right direction! :)

Comment: For better help sooner, post your code as an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) that demonstrates your problem. This allows users to copy/paste and reproduce your issue.

Comment: What happens if you replace `Matchers.<DatePeriod>any()` with `any(DatePeriod.class)` ?

Comment: At first glance I can't see anything obviously wrong. Double-check that getDTO is not `final`—those can't be mocked with Mockito—and that it's not actually a previous or subsequent stub causing that error.

Comment: @DuncanJones - I would like to, but I had to change it as it is my companys code and I dont how they like it if I post code on public forums so I simplified it. I could however next make a runnable example.. I'll try to do that from now on, thanks

Comment: @DavidWallace - I tried it, same error occurs.

Comment: @JeffBowman - I have checked that and it is not the case - but thanks for the suggestion :)

Comment: OK, next question - are there any OTHER calls to Mockito methods in the same test?  Sometimes, errors like this one are reported against a different line from the one where the actual problem is.  It would be best if you could post the whole test method; but if you can't, then post any lines that have Mockito calls in.

Comment: haha - I just found the error.. huge error 40! - instead of mocking the dependant services and dao's I was trying to mock the very service i'm testing. 

I removed the line and mocked the other dependant services and now it seems to work as intended!! - sorry for wasting your time!

Comment: I closed the topic, but thank you for your help everyone :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since my error was a PEBKAC and I solved it on my own I will be answering my own question

**EDIT**

> *instead of mocking the dependant services and dao's I was trying to
>   mock the very service i'm testing. I removed the line and mocked the
>   other dependant services and now it seems to work as intended*

(copied from [Mockito throws InvalidUseOfMatchersException while mocking a method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18097757/mockito-throws-invaliduseofmatchersexception-while-mocking-a-method/20241651?noredirect=1#comment26533537_18097757))

Comment: To make it an answer you should answer it `Problem Exists Between Keyboard And Chair` would be an answer for the most questions, if it would be an answer ....

Comment: I already did answer it.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18097757/mockito-throws-invaliduseofmatchersexception-while-mocking-a-method/20241651?noredirect=1#comment26533537_18097757

Comment: updated answer post to include the answer from the comments to make it clearer for readers